# Not able to give space as a value in the Input property in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-input

I am trying to create generic controls like this

dynamic-control.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngo-button',
  template: `<button [ngClass]=class type={{type}}>{{message}}</button>`,
  styles: [`.one{border:solid 2px yellow} .two{background-color:pink} .three{
  background-color: blue;
}`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
   @Input() type: string = 'button';
  @Input() class: string = 'one three';
  @Input() message: string = 'submit';
}
```

main-component.html

```
<ngo-button [class]='btn two' (click)='somefunc()'></ngo-button>
```

now i want to pass two classes to the button, but when i am trying to pass it this way, i am getting error

> [class]='btn two'

i suppose, we are not allowed to add space in the input parameter, is there another way to implement it?

[this is the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5k9ruz)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<ngo-button [class]="'btn two'" (click)='somefunc()'></ngo-button>
```

Default syntax of Angular. You have to provide a string in quotes if you use the `[input]` notation.

Otherwise :

```
<ngo-button class="btn two" (click)='somefunc()'></ngo-button>
```

Although I have to say, it really don't understand why you use an input to provide the classes of your component.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [ngClass]**

```
<ngo-button [ngClass]="{'first class':{expression},'second class':{expression}}" (click)='somefunc()'></ngo-button>
```

**N.B:** expressions are like : true/false, 2>1 etc.

**remember** : remove the {} of {expression}

Comment: This will not result in the same behaviour as the question asked, as the classes are applied to the host element `<ngo-button>` instead of the internal template `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use square brackets [] in Angular, you're telling the Angular compiler that what follows is an expression to be parsed. Since `btn two` isn't a valid expression, you're getting a parsing error. What you actually want to do is:

`[class]="'btn two'"`.

It's worth mentioning that because you've chosen to name your input 'class,' you may potentially have issues later on with Angular both passing your values in as an input parameter *and* applying the value as a class to the parent element.

Comment: You provided another wrong syntax (also, consider upvoting an existing answer instead of parroting it)

Comment: @Maryannah Your answer wasn't there when I commented. It appeared only when I refreshed.

Comment: sure, I understand, then you wouldn't mind deleting it :) anyway, keep it if you want, I'm only giving you the best practices to adopt on stack overflow